# ASP.NET MVC 4 User Authentication

Tags: c#, session, asp.net-mvc-4, authorize-attribute

I am trying to write a Login method that authenticates and authorizes users into my web site developed with ASP.NET MVC 4. The problem is, although I call the FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie method after validating the user inside the Login method and redirect to ViewProfile action, User.Identity.IsAuthenticated returns still false in my custom Authorize attribute object.

I gave the code below:

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
public ActionResult Login(LoginModel model)
{
    if (Membership.ValidateUser(model.Username, model.Password))
    {
        FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.Username, model.RememberMe);
        return this.RedirectToAction("ViewProfile");
    }
    ModelState.AddModelError("", "The user name or password provided is incorrect.");
    return View(model);
}

[MyAuthorize(Roles = "Super Role, Seeker")]
public ActionResult ViewProfile()
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
    ...
    }
}
```

And here is the code of the MyAuthorizeAttribute class

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = false)]
public class MyAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        if (httpContext == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("httpContext");

        var user = httpContext.User;
        if (!user.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            return false;

        ...
    }
}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Can you see the Forms Authentication cookie being set and sent on the subsequent call when redirecting?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the ones who may use FormsAuthentication and face a similar situation, be sure that the following configuration exists under your web.config file

```
<authentication mode="Forms"></authentication>
```

Now everything works fine